# Core Data document based multiple nib based on selection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, document-based

I'm building a Core Data document based application. In the app there's a main view (NSTableView) and an inspector view. Both views are separate nib files. The content of the inspector view should depend on the selected row in the main view. I have three controller files:

- DocumentWindowController (master controller)
- ItemsViewController (main view)
- SchedulesViewController (part of the inspector)

Every controller owns a nib file. How is it possible to change the content of the inspector when the user selects another row in the main view's table?

I tried to make it work as follows:

- Every controller has it's own NSArrayController, which is set up in the DocumentWindowController. The DocumentWindowController gets its managedObjectContext from [[self document] managedObjectContext]
- When a user clicks a row in the ItemsViewController's tableView, an NSNotification is posted, with [NSTableView selectedRow] as a parameter. Then a fetch request is being made.

My intuition says I have to do this with Cocoa bindings.
I searched on Stackoverflow and google but I just can't make it work. If everything is in one nib file is very easy to accomplish. What is the best/most used way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the same paradigm as the table view and create a data source for your inspector view.

```
@protocol InspectorDataSource <NSObject>
- (void) inspectorView:(InspectorView*)inspectorView managedObjectSelected:(NSManagedObject*)managedObject;
@end
```

Your inspector view controller would then have the data source as a property.

```
@interface InspectorViewController : UIViewController{
    @public
    id<InspectorDataSource> dataSource;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<InspectorDataSource> dataSource;
```